# On bounding a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We know the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} $$

converges since we can compare with $1/n^{3/2}$ which is a convergent p-series.

Now, is it possible to show that

$$ \sum \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} < 2 $$

??

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} + \int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)} \approx 1.9667$$